Why God Sent Elijah to THAT Particular Widow and NOT to Any Other?
According to Luke 4:25-26 (NAB):

Indeed, I tell you, there were many widows in Israel in the days of Elijah when the sky was closed for three and a half years and a severe famine spread over the entire land. It was to none of these that Elijah was sent, but only to a widow in Zarephath in the land of Sidon.

QUESTION: Why did God send the prophet to that particular widow and not to any of the others instead?
Thank you.

We are not told so we do not know.  Perhaps this widow was judged by God to be the most receptive to Elijah.  Again, we are not told and any conclusion is speculative.

The context makes it so clear it's almost certain, @Dottard. And that those in the synagogue were angry shows that the meaning was depreciatory to them. There is some narrow band of speculation left within the reasoning but a plain and sensible reading of the whole context leaves no-one in any doubt. Please refer to the answers provided.

Short Answer: Scripture does not provide a detailed, explicit explanation for why God sent Elijah specifically to the widow of Zarephath rather than to any of the other widows in Israel. However, through the context, we might infer some reasons:
Note the background:

24 And he said, “Truly, I say to you, no prophet is acceptable in his
hometown. 25 But in truth, I tell you, there were many widows in
Israel in the days of Elijah, when the heavens were shut up three
years and six months, and a great famine came over all the land, 26
and Elijah was sent to none of them but only to Zarephath, in the land
of Sidon, to a woman who was a widow. 27 And there were many lepers
in Israel in the time of the prophet Elisha, and none of them was
cleansed, but only Naaman the Syrian.” 28 When they heard these
things, all in the synagogue were filled with wrath.

No prophet is acceptable in his hometown. Is it not true that people often fail to recognize the authority of someone they are familiar with?
The widow was not from Israel; however, she showed faith and obedience by providing for Elijah. All this while her circumstances were dire. Compare her story with the unbelief among the Israelites at the time.
What do we know?

In Elijah's day, the people of Israel were steeped in idolatry and disobedience. See: 1 Kings 16:30-33, 18:18, 19:10.
Elijah was sent to the widow in Zarephath. Knowing this then, the widow of Zarephath was likely a Gentile. See: 1 Kings 17:9.
If this is true then Elijah was sent to the widow in Zarephath, and Elisha healed Naaman the Syrian, both of whom were Gentiles.

What might Jesus want us to learn from this?

Familiarity can breed contempt, but we must not fail to recognize God’s work.
God's favor is not limited to Israel but is available to all who have faith.

If one believed in the special status of Israel as God's chosen people, then the idea that God’s blessings could be given to outsiders was offensive.
Then comes Jesus who references this widow in Zarephath and Naaman the Syrian implying a critique of Israel's unbelief and disobedience. Almost as if Jesus is suggesting in their midst that Gentiles showed more faith than Israelites. It could be seen as rather provocative right? An indictment of their spiritual state.

Ok. +1. Thank you.

Contrast and Context The context of this statement by Jesus is the incident when Jesus presented Himself to His own townfolk, BUT was soundly rejected: "He couldn't be important because he is just the son of a local man!"
As a result, the local people were shutting themselves up from experiencing any miracles. Without faith in Him there could be no miraculous healings like there were being done in Capernaum. They had taunted Him with  , "Whatsoever we have heard done in Capernaum, do also here in your country."
Jesus refused to comply, and reminded them of past history when God also turned His back on corrupt, unfaithful Israel, and ministered to foreigners instead: a widow in Sidon, and a leper in Syria. So also, Jesus would minister to the people of Capernaum, and ignore the people of Nazareth.
Specific Widow When mentioning the widow, Jesus was making a contrast between the people of Israel and the foreigner...He was not contrasting all the widows, or pushing the idea of a certain, specific widow in contrast to other ordinary widows. The wording of the KJV is more clear:  Many widows were in Israel in the days of Elias...but unto none of them was Elias sent, save unto Sarepta, a city of Sidon, unto a woman that was a widow.

There were many widows in Israel...yet Elijah was sent to none of them except to a widow at Zarephath in Sidon. (New Revised Standard Version, 1989)


There were many widows in Israel, to be sure...yet it was to none of these that Elijah was sent, but to a widow at Sarepta in the territory of Sidon. (NEB, 1970)


There were many widows in Israel...and to none of them was Elias sent, but rather to a widowed woman in Sarepta of Sidon. (Confraternity, 1950)

Elias could have gone to any widow in Sidon (who then benefited from his presence)...but not any widow in Israel! That is the point Jesus was making to the faithless people of Nazareth.
Although the NAB translation used the word, "only", it must be read with the understanding of the contrasting idea of "save" (old English) or "except" (contrasting the two nations)...and not "particular" or "exclusive" (pitting one widow against another).
ConsequenceTo confirm this thought, notice the resulting thinking and actions of the town folk: they were filled with wrath, and rose up, and thrust Him out of the city...(Luke 4:28-29) They knew the message was not about a specific widow, but about a foreigner being more privileged than an Israelite! And that was too hard a pill to swallow.
